# How can i change this Dateadd to selective dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In the end of my big procedure i have previously made it so i can write example: "2" to get sales information for February. But now i want to change this so i can  write the specific dates, because we want to fetch some more data.

Example of what I want to write: 29.01.2014 - 28.02.2014

Code:

```
 WHERE  isa.sales_date >= Dateadd(mm, ( @year - 1900 ) * 12 + ( @month - 1 ), 
                         0) 
       AND isa.sales_date < Dateadd(mm, ( @year - 1900 ) * 12 + @month, 0)
```

Comment: The question is almost solved beneath! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:
Have two parameters:

```
@startDate varchar(10) --2014-01-01
@endDate varchar(10) --2014-01-29
```

And modify code like:

```
   WHERE  isa.sales_date >= convert(datetime, @startDate, 120)
   AND isa.sales_date < DATEADD(DAY, 1, (convert(datetime, @endDate, 120))
```

The DATEADD part is to include all sales until the end of the last day.

Comment: Yes, this is what i am looking for great sir! But i cant seem to get any data when i run it, in which format do i have to write the dates? i also get this error: Procedure execution failed
22007 - [SQL Server]The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: What is the exact input your are passing to startDate and endDate? I assumed '@startDate = '29.01.2014'' and '@endDate = '28.02.2014'' ?

Comment: -  2014-01-01 and 2014-01-29 for testing

Comment: For automatic conversion you can write the dates in YYYY/MM/DD format but you should really use the appropriate function to convert your string input to a date eg convert with a format mask

Comment: I just wrote YYYY/MM/DD and it is showing the error: Procedure execution failed
22007 - [SQL Server]The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Edited answer to accommodate test input

Comment: Hey, i tested 20 and it worked out. What is the difference in changing this to 120 and 20? :) Thank you sooo much btw. made my day

Comment: No difference as far as I can see. How is the data though? Are you getting all the data according to date range?